# using boost::serialize declared in struct into another struct

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, struct

I am new to programming and C++ and seem to have run into this problem.

I am creating a config file with various sensor offsets, and storing it as xml that can be read by other classes using boost::serialization load.

As all sensors have the same kind of offset, I want to make a generic struct with offset definitions. I would like to keep the serialize and save/load in the generic stuct and only instantiate in a different struct when need be.

Each sensor has its own struct, so the other classes only need to use the sensor struct they need.

Originally, I had the serialize/save/load in each sensor struct, and it worked fine. But after moving this to generic struct I cant seem to be able to call it.

The code is:

```
10 #pragma once
 11 #ifndef OFFSET_CONFIG_H
 12 #define OFFSET_CONFIG_H
 13 
 14 #include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
 15 #include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
 16 #include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
 17 #include <fstream>
 18 #include <string>
 19 
 20 typedef struct Offset
 21 {
 22     std::string name;            // Offsets type.
 23     double offsetX;
 24     double offsetY;
 25     double offsetZ;
 26     double roll;
 27     double pitch;
 28     double yaw;
 29 
 30     template<class Archive>
 31     void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
 32     {
 33         using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
 34         ar & make_nvp("offsetType", name);
 35         ar & make_nvp("OffsetX", offsetX);
 36         ar & make_nvp("OffsetY", offsetY);
 37         ar & make_nvp("OffsetZ", offsetZ);
 38         ar & make_nvp("Roll", roll);
 39         ar & make_nvp("Pitch", pitch);
 40         ar & make_nvp("Yaw", yaw);
 41     }
 42 
 43     void save(const std::string& filename)
 44     {
 45         std::fstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::out);
 46         boost::archive::xml_oarchive xml(ofs);
 47         xml << boost::serialization::make_nvp("temp", *this);
 48     }
 49 
 50 };
 51  
 70 struct LaserOffset
 71 {
 72   Offset laser;
 90   laser.serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);
 91   //laser.save(const std::string& filename);
 98 };

168 #endif
```

The error it is throwing currently is:

```
OffsetConfig.h:90: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘laser’ with no type 

OffsetConfig.h:90: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘.’ token
```

Can anyone help me with what am I doing wrong? and how to use the serialise/save elements from the struct and maybe how to save it for individual structs?

Comment: Forgot to add, calling serialize also results in the error "struct LaserOffset' has no member 'serialize'

Comment: You do not need `typedef struct` in C++, simply `struct` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthias said, In your code snip,

```
 typedef struct Offset {};
```

should be written like,

```
struct Offset {};
```

Cause in c++ you can define a struct object by `Offset _offset;`, while in c you should use `struct Offset _offset;`. So you would like to use `typedef struct Offset{} Offset;`

Generally, *ISO C++ forbids declaration of `your_var` with no type* means gcc cannot find the declaration of `your_var`. When it happens, you should check the include file, the definition of `your_var` and the namespace, which normally cause this error.

BTW, `#pargma once` and `#ifndef ... #define ...` do the same thing.